# The annoyed configuration of java-6-openjdk

Tags: configuration, java, environment-variables, openjdk

I want to change the java environment to  **java-6-openjdk**.
**/etc/environment:**

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/
CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib
```

**java -version**:

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.5) (6b20-1.9.5-0ubuntu1~10.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

**javac -version**:`javac 1.6.0_20`

But in the shell:
the `echo $JAVA_HOME` result is **/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22** while the `$CLASSPATH` is **/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/lib**.

How to find the other files in which  `$JAVA_HOME` & `$CLASSPATH` value  is setted  by the `java-6-sun-1.6.0.22` location?

Answer (score 1):

In my system (Ubuntu 10.04.LTS) `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk` is symbolic link pointed to `/usr/lib/java-6-openjdk` directory.

In `/etc/environments` `JAVA_HOME` refers the link only.

Maybe you check this link in your system.

Comment: what should the value for the variable `JAVA_HOME` be, then?

Comment: For example: `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"`

Comment: In quotes as PATH above?  No quotes?  On separate line is what I have.

Comment: I copied from bash `export` list. In case of `echo $JAVA_HOME`, there is no quotes, only: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 1 JREs in your system, you're supposed to select the default by running:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

...it will automatically set all the environment variables where required. Check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JavaInstallation for more information. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work - doesn't set the environment variables